# NumberFormatException in Stars.java

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have been working at this for a while and I keep getting the same error.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
        at StarsTable.addArray(StarsTable.java:50)
        at StarsTable.<init>(StarsTable.java:24)
        at Stars.main(Stars.java:7)`

Stars.java

```
public class Stars 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String inFile = args[0];
        StarsTable stars = new StarsTable(inFile); line 7
        System.out.println("Program to output a star map.");
        System.out.println("Written by ");
        System.out.println(stars.title());
        Integer[][] a = stars.getArray();
    System.out.print("-");
    for (int x = 0; x < a.length; x ++)
        System.out.print("--");
    for (int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("\n:");
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        {
            if(stars.checkIfStar(i,j) == 1)
            {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            else
                System.out.print("  ");
        }
    }


}
```

}

StarsTable.java

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.*;


public class StarsTable 
{
    private ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private String title;
    private String readLine = null;
    private int rows = 0;
    private Integer array[][];

    public StarsTable( String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new 
                    BufferedReader(new FileReader( fileName));
            title = br.readLine();
            while(( readLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                addArray(readLine); line 24
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("File Not Found. Please "
                    + "enter filename in command line.");
            System.exit(1);
        }


    }

    public String title()
    {
        return title;
    }


    public void addArray(String readLine)
    {
        int i = 0;
        String[] splitLine = readLine.split(" ");
        for(i = 0; i < splitLine.length; i++)
        {
            a.add(Integer.valueOf(splitLine[i])); Line 50
        }
        rows++;
    }

    public Integer[][] getArray()
    {
        toArray();
        return array;
    }

    public void toArray()
    {
        array = new Integer[a.size() / rows][rows];
        int g = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < (a.size() / rows); i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < rows; k++)
            {
                array[i][k] = a.get(g);             
                g++;
            }
        }
    }
    public int checkIfStar(int i, int k)
    {
        Integer check = 0;
        // Corners
        if (i == 0 && k == 0)
            check = array[i][k] + array[i + 1][k] + array[i][k + 1];
        else if (i == array[0].length && k == 0)
            check = array[i][k] + array[i - 1][k] + array[i][k-1];
        else if (i == 0 && k == array.length)
            check = array[i][k] + array[i][k - 1] + array[i + 1][k];
        else if (i == array[0].length && k == array.length)
            check = array[i][k] + array[i][k - 1] + array[i - 1][k];
        // Edges
        else if (i == 0) //Top
            check = array[i][k] + array[i][k + 1] + array[i - 1][k] + array[i + 1][k];    
        else if (k == 0) // Left
            check = array[i][k] + array[i][k - 1] + array[i][k + 1] + array[i + 1][k];    
        else if (i == array[0].length) //Right
            check = array[i][k] + array[i][k - 1] + array[i][k + 1] + array[i - 1][k];    
        else if (k == array.length) // Bottom
            check = array[i][k] + array[i][k - 1] + array[i - 1][k] + array[i + 1][k];    
        // Middle
        else
            check = array[i][k] + array[i][k - 1] + array[i][k + 1] + array[i - 1][k] + array[i + 1][k];
        check = check / 5;
        if (check < 5)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is the problem with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is the input being passed to this program?

Comment: Where is the error can you mark it for us?

Comment: Its a text file with a title line at the top then rows of numbers separated by spaces

Comment: I added the line number next to where each line is occuring

Comment: You've got a blank line in your input file.  You need to add a condition to your program so that it ignores blank lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the code like this,

```
        for (i = 0; i < splitLine.length; i++)
        {
            a.add(Integer.valueOf(splitLine[i].trim()));
        }
```

instead of

```
        for (i = 0; i < splitLine.length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                a.add(Integer.valueOf(splitLine[i].trim()));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception Occurs while formating : " + splitLine[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This isn't wrong.  But it's not quite as good as explicitly checking for blank lines, like Elliott's solution does.  It would be far better to let the exception be thrown in the case where the value is actually wrong (like, not a number), and only swallow it in the case where the input is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to your (seeming) expectations, the value "" has no Integer value; try one of -

```
if (! splitLine[i].equals("")) {
  a.add(Integer.valueOf(splitLine[i]));
} else {
  a.add(0); // <-- to just add 0.
}
```

or

```
// this is slower, and I probably wouldn't do this.
try {
  a.add(Integer.valueOf(splitLine[i]));
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
  nfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to get rid of `addArray` entirely.  Just use a `Scanner` to read the file, instead of a `BufferedReader`.  Then you can read it number by number using the `nextInt()` method, and `hasNext()` to check when the file is finished.

That way, you don't have to read line by line, you don't have to use `split` to split the line into numbers, and you don't have to parse each number.  In effect, you have re-invented three separate wheels in your code; and introduced a bug along the way.

It's always best to know the API, and use the goodies that it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
public void addArray(String readLine)
{
    int i = 0;
    String[] splitLine = readLine.split(" ");
    for(i = 1; i < splitLine.length; i++) // start at 1
    {
        a.add(Integer.valueOf(splitLine[i].trim()));
    }
    rows++;
}
```

Comment: How will you pick up the first number on each line?

Comment: @DavidWallace The first element of each array isn't a number, it's some sort of string isn't it? The OP posten input.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a util function to deal with the exception, such as,

```
int safeParseInt(String input){
     try{
         return Integer.parseInt(input);
     }catch(Exception e){
      //error log or print
      return 0;
     }
}

String[] strs = line.split(" ");
for(i = 1; i < strs.length; i++)
{
    array.add(safeParseInt(strs[i]));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, spelling error! The function name is "safeParseInt" not "safePaseInt"